# Issue in forming paramters of RequestBody for okhttp

Tags: android, request, okhttp

I have requirement of adding multiple course details in a Requestbody.

I have to use [] for it.

If I want to add multiple courses I have to add like below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < listStudentCourseData.size(); i++) {
            requestBody.put("fees[]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrFees());
            requestBody.put("course_id[]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrCourseId());
            requestBody.put("duration[]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrDuration());
            requestBody.put("course_status[]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrCourseStatus());
            requestBody.put("certificate[]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrCertificate());
            requestBody.put("book_material[]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrBookMaterial());
            requestBody.put("bag[]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrBag());
        }
```

The issue is only single value i can add for courselist. You can see I have used for loop to add same parameters multiple time (As per backend requirement)

I have debug the code and found that all parameter values inside for loop are getting replaced with last.
I can add only one course details.

What might be the issue ?

Or

How can I achieve that (Adding multiple values - array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.What might be the issue ?**
The Issue is that requestBody takes key-value pairs of which the key must be unique. therefore your requestBody saves only the last values from the loop.

**Solution**

for (int i = 0; i < listStudentCourseData.size(); i++) {

requestBody.put("fees[" + i + "]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrFees());

```
requestBody.put("course_id["+ i + "]",listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrCourseId());

requestBody.put("duration["+ i + "]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrDuration());

requestBody.put("course_status[" + i + ]",listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrCourseStatus());

requestBody.put("certificate[" + i + "]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrCertificate());

requestBody.put("book_material[" + i + "]",listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrBookMaterial());

requestBody.put("bag[" + i + "]", listStudentCourseData.get(i).getStrBag());
```

}

I have not tested it but hope it works. happy coding

Comment: ya this is what i am thinking for.

Comment: Great and happy to help JaiminModi